# Add extra package to scan to entity manager using Spring configuration?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-batch, entitymanager

I have a Spring Batch application that has a Spring context configuration that normally each batch job would reference. This way each batch job uses the same entity manager.

batch-context.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- ... -->

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.domain" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class"> org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">100</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jbc.batch_size">1000</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- ... -->

</beans>
```

Now in my specific batch job context (call it ExampleBatch.xml) I want to add another package to scan to the already defined entityManagerFactory bean. Is this possible?

ExampleBatch.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd">

    <!-- ... -->    

    <import resource="classpath:batch-context.xml" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryWithExtraPackages"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        parent="entityManagerFactory">

        <!-- How do I override the packagesToScan property on the already defined entityManagerFactory bean?-->
        <property 
            name="packagesToScan" 
            value ="com.example.domain,com.example.domain.abstraction"
        />
    </bean>

    <!-- ... -->

</beans>
```

The way I have it right now will not work because it complains that "`No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 2`"

Is trying to override the "packagesToScan" property the right approach to take in this scenario? Is there a better way to accomplish this behavior?

**Edit:**

I was able to accomplish what I needed using the `property-override` functionality. Below is the updated ExampleBatch.xml that I went with

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd">

    <!-- ... -->    

    <import resource="classpath:batch-context.xml" />

    <context:property-override properties-ref="entityManagerOverride"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerOverride"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="properties">
            <util:properties>
                <prop key="entityManagerFactory.packagesToScan">com.example.domain,com.example.batch.module.domain</prop>
            </util:properties>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- ... -->

</beans>
```

So far Spring does not yell at me that this is an invalid configuration. Have yet to determine if this is in fact producing the desired outcome.

**Edit 2:**

The property-override method does not appear to be sufficient. It is a valid configuration but after inspecting the entity manager at runtime like this:

```
for (EntityType<?> entity : manager.getMetamodel().getEntities()) {
    String name = entity.getName();
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

It only contains entities from the com.example.domain package.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: This question helped lead me to my solution as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382070/overriding-property-file-using-spring

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it now, you really define two separate beans - one called `entityManagerFactory` and the other one `entityManagerFactoryWithExtraPackages`.

There are several ways to solve your very request:

1. Just get rid of one of the beans - merge the definitions into one. 
   I only guess it's not an option for you, otherwise you wouldn't ask.
2. Define the `entityManagerFactory` as abstract, then you end up having one bean anyway.
3. Use the property override mechanism. This fits the scenarios, where you are not in control of the 'top' bean and despite that you want to re-configure (literally override the values of the properties of) beans defined there.

Comment: I was able to use the property override mechanism... I will post my solution as an edit in a few minutes

Comment: I thought property override would work but upon further inspection, it doesn't appear to behave as expected. My suspicion is that the entity manager gets constructed when it is defined in the batch-context.xml file, then the property is overridden. Since the entityManger is already created it doesn't scan the packages again. That's just a guess... I don't know if that is actually what's happening.

Comment: #1 and #2 are not options. I want any other batch to be able to use the entityManager as defined in batch-context.xml. I do not want to force every batch to have to in some way configure entity manager.

Comment: I know little of `spring-batch`, but I am pretty sure that if you use the property override mechanism the overridden value never gets set, so Spring ends up calling a single setter once (with the overriding value). This is exactly what 'property override' mechanism is designed for.      Are you sure the `ExampleBatch.xml` file is part of the same Spring context as the `batch-context.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this:

```
<property 
        name="packagesToScan" 
        value ="com.example.domain,com.example.domain.abstraction"/>
```

with this:

```
<property name="packagesToScan">
     <array>
          <value>com.example.domain</value>
          <value>com.example.domain.abstraction</value>
     </array>
 </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it fits your packages organization, you may try

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.domain.*" />
```

In your batch-context.xml, so your ExampleBatch.xml doesn't have anymore to "override" the parent.

Another way to dig is using placeholder; in batch-context.xml, you would use :

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="${packageList}" />
```

while in ExampleBatch.xml you would declare the placeholder with the appropriate value, as explained for example here : http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/

Comment: Unfortunately, your first suggestion does not fit my scenario. The package structure is slightly different. Your second suggestion has potential... I will try it.