# Spring - java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing a Spring Boot application which has a dependency added. This dependency has a spring.xml file. I am scanning this xml file and creating beans as well. One of the beans is looking for hibernate.properties in classpath. I have added this property file under resources folder of my application. However I still see the exception listed below. Please can you let me know what I am missing?

```
 <util:properties id="HibernateProperties" location="classpath:hibernate.properties"/>
```

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [hibernate.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: Did you try `classpath:/hibernate.properties`?

Comment: Removing `classpath:` worked for me when running `mvn spring-boot:run`. It also worked when I packaged and ran `java -jar target\App.war`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here some doc from spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-classpath-wildcards)

> Ant-style patterns with classpath: resources are not guaranteed to
>   find matching resources if the root package to search is available in
>   multiple class path locations. This is because a resource such as
>
> com/mycompany/package1/service-context.xml may be in only one
>   location, but when a path such as
>
> classpath:com/mycompany/**/service-context.xml

so,

```
<util:properties id="HibernateProperties" location="classpath*:hibernate.properties"/>
```

may give you better chance.

but,

> Please note that classpath*: when combined with Ant-style patterns
>   will only work reliably with at least one root directory before the
>   pattern starts, unless the actual target files reside in the file
>   system. This means that a pattern like classpath*:*.xml will not
>   retrieve files from the root of jar files but rather only from the
>   root of expanded directories. This originates from a limitation in the
>   JDK’s ClassLoader.getResources() method which only returns file system
>   locations for a passed-in empty string (indicating potential roots to
>   search).

Comment: Thanks @kuhajeyan. I cannot modify the spring.xml as it is within an external jar. Is there anything else that could be done in this case?

Comment: @PunterVicky i guess it should be possible to define your own one that will override what exists already in classpath , Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382070/overriding-property-file-using-spring